# How to align mesh parts?

Tags: mesh

Suppose I have a mesh containing, among other things, two cubes of different sizes, both oriented so that the main axes of these cubes are parallel to the world axes.

[image: what I have]

How can I align these cubes so that the top planes are at the same z coordinate, leaving other coordinates unchanged?

[image: what I want]

One way to do it is to separate these cubes into two different objects, and to align these, but the original object contains a lot more than the two cubes, so it needs to be reconstructed after the alignment, which is too much effort.

Comment: could you please make some screenshots to make it more understandable?

Comment: moonboots is right, indeed.  Pictures added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Snapping**.

Select the vertices you want to move.

Enable snapping (magnet icon) and set it to *Snap to Vertices*.

In a lateral Orthographic view move the vertices you want to align.

[image]

Other tools to be aware of:

**Scaling to zero**.

Select all of the vertces and scale to $0$ on the axis you need.

In this example all of the vertices are scaled on the z axis, this is done pressing <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>$0$</kbd>:

[image]

For a more precise alignment, **copy the coordinates of a vertex** in a given axis, and make the selected vertices be at such coordinates using the Item > Transform tab.

You can set the coordinates to global.

[image]

To copy and paste values, just move the cursor over to the value you want to copy and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste

Comment: Took me a while to understand the semantics of the various snapping options, but this is exactly what I need! Thanks for sorting me out

Comment: @eezacque Hey :). If susu's answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted **✓**.

Comment: @JachymMichal I like your answer better.

Comment: Thanks :) Perhaps I'll get the sweet sweet green checkmark next time :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use active vertex for snapping

1. Select the vertices you want to move
2. Use *Pivot > Active Element* and enable *Vertex snapping*
3. The last selected vertex will be used for snapping

[image]